# Google Cloud Message Android Key

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I set up Google Cloud Message over this site https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start .At the end of the process, I got a json file for my Android project, and an Server Key. When I was looking in the Google Api Console I also got an Android Key, although, in contrast to for example Google maps, I dont have to insert a key into the Manifest. So what is this Android Key for?

Comment: Your Android Key might probably be from another project of yours?

Answer (score 0):

The following link might help
[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

The key that you get is to be used in your server script (eg. PHP) to send the data bundle to your android device.

```
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key= YOUR_KEY_HERE
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

The message received should be handled in Android to generate a push notification and maybe to store the data in internal databases.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
   String message = data.getString("message");
   Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
   Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
   // Handle received message here.
}
```

For detailed implementation refer this tutorial.
[GCM Implementation.](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/)